# two profiles in same plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create an upward and downward profile of temperature w.r.t 
 height. My problem is I am not able to separate the two parts and hence the result is not what I want. below is the imaginary data:

```
height,temp
0,50.5
200,25.2
400,11.6
600,4.9
800,2.2
1000,1.4
800,1.3
600,2.6
400,10.1
200,16.4
0,20.8
```

When I plot height vs temp , I want a profile until 0-1000(upward) and a second profile 1000-0(downward)in the same plot using ggplot2. How can I separate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the question, the simplest way would be to add a supplementary column to specify which points correspond to the "up" and which to the "down" profile. SOmething like:

```
df <-  mutate(df, trend = c(rep("up",6), rep("down",5))) 
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = height, y = temp, color = trend)) + 
     geom_line()
p
```

[image]

If you want to "connect" the two lines at 1000, you'd just have to add a "fake" replicated point at height = 1000 and assign it to "down".